# How to create a simple tool bar along with left / right swipe animation in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Hi I am new to Xamarin Forms, Native - iOS is my background.
Now I want to create a tool bar with items like ONE, TWO, THREE,...etc and also swipe the tool bar items in both Android & iOS devices.

For creating tool bar items I am doing like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="ToolBarDemo.Views.CustomToolBar">

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <ToolbarItem Name="ONE" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
  <ToolbarItem Name="TWO" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
  <ToolbarItem Name="THREE" Activated="OnClick"  Order="Primary" Priority="1" />
 </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
</ContentPage>
```

Now I am able to see the my tool bar items, But **I need to swipe / scroll the tool bar items either  left to right or right to left.**

Based on the Tool bar item I need to update the ContentPage or I need to show the different screens with respective tool bar item.

**Mac Min with 10.13.2 version,
Visual Studio For Mac Enterprise Edition with 7.4.3 version.**

Comment: like this : https://www.journaldev.com/12958/android-tablayout-viewpager

Comment: @G.hakim Sorry and thank you for the late reply.
 
like this : journaldev.com/12958/android-tablayout-viewpager it is ok, But at the same time I need to swipe top menu bar items (TAB1, TAB2, ...)  also I need a sample code in Xamarin Forms not in Java or Android.
Thank you in advance

Comment: will this work? :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page

Comment: @G.hakim Thank you for your reply I will look into it.